# Updating .ini file getting messy after store

Tags: java, ini

i have edited and updated an ini file but after saving it it became so messy and lost all file structure

this is a sample before editing

```
[Visual]
POSTPROCESS_BRIGHTNESS=32
HIGH_EFFECT=0
HIGH_EFFECT2=0
TEXTURELOD=0
WATEREFFECT=0
GRASSRENDERING=0
SHADOW=0
```

and this is what i got after saving

```
#Thu Sep 28 21:23:35 EET 2017
layout_charsel_select_y=722
layout_charsel_select_x=483
GAMMA=4
POSTPROCESS_BRIGHTNESS=32
layout_weapondestroy_y=100
layout_chattingctrl_y=634
layout_weapondestroy_x=100
```

I have used java properties and ini4j both led to the same issue, so is there any way to fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the source code of your program.